# How to use auto.arima when attaining different results with a manual model selection?

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection

I have daily sales data for over 2 years. I am having several questions of how to manually define model order and how to do it using auto_arima.

**Manual**

The first step I do it to see if my data is stationary, if it is then d = 0; otherwise I do a check to see what my d should be. In the case of my data, using the Dicky Fuller test I can accept the alternative hypothesis that my data is stationary on the 95% significance level (p < 0.05). Now here arises my first question.

I want to be able to predict 28 days ahead, and want to be able to see how my model scores using a test set. So I hold out (28 days) for this.

Now when I do the stationarity check, do I have to do it on the whole dataset, or only on the training dataset?

Next up I plot my ACF and PACF plots and see spikes every 7 lags (so 7, 14, 21, ...). So I assume my model orders for AR and MA to be 7. This concludes to an ARMA model (7, 0, 7)?

**Estimate selection**

Now when I use the auto_arima function. First of again, do I use the whole dataset to find the model order, or only the training dataset? If I use the whole dataset, I assume I only fit the model on the training dataset?

The thing is, whatever I do (whole dataset, or only training dataset), I get very different model order results, ARMA(6,0,1). Even though I specify max_p and max_q to be 7. When comparing these models on the test set, the ARMA(7, 0, 7) performs way better (the selection happends based on AIC, and I assume that that is the reason since it penalizes having more features?).

**Concluding question**

The question thus is, if I want to split up my dataset in training and test dataset, do I only use the training dataset for the checks (Dicky Fuller & auto_arima)? And also why does my manual + intuitively model not occurr in the estimate selection?

Comment: Why do you use underscore in place of a dot? Or are these not R functions and their arguments you are referring to?

Comment: It's the python counterpart, whic I think is auto_arima

Comment: OK. I just thought if some people follow questions about `auto.arima` (the popularity of which absolutely dominates those on `auto_arima` here at Cross Validated), they may miss the ones about `auto_arima` just because of the unfortunate punctuation.

Comment: I'll try and convert my code to the R counterpart and see what results I get, but I guess the problem will stay the same